# To get all similar objects from a Java object

Tags: java, class, apache-commons

I have a java class names Activity. It has several objects attached.

```
class Activity{
  int id;
  Book book;
  Address address;
  Man man;
  Woman woman;

}

class Man{
   String name;
   List<Address> address;
   List<Appointee> appointees;
}

class Woman{
    String name;   
    List<Phone> phones;
    List<Address> address;
    Manager manager;
}

class Manager{
   String position;
   Adddress address;
}

class Appointee{
  String type;
  List<Address> address;
}
```

Note that Activity main class is created from an xsd schmea using jaxb. I cannot add any additional methods into it.
So as can be seen, when an object of Activity is created, it has objects of type Address in different areas. Activity class has an object of class Address, and also within man, woman, manager and appointee there are lists of objects belonging to class Address. Is there any way to get all these 'Address' objects from the Activity class using stream function or Apache commonUtils function. Otherwise, I need to traverse through the entire Activity object and get the objects of Address.

Comment: "traverse through the entire class and get the collection" is less work than you think. Also, any method that "magically" traverses the objects is not recommendable in terms of performance.

Comment: Can you show your approach first ? And do you have List of `Activity` ? Simplest way is create as list add 2 list (using `addAll` of list) and single one.

Answer (score 1):

```
Activity activity = ....

List<Address> all = Stream.of(
                  activity.getMan().getAddresses(),
                  activity.getWoman().getAddresses(),
                  Arrays.asList(activity.getAddress()))
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You could use `Stream::of` that will concatenate the needed pieces together. So first get the man addresses, then women address, then the address itself from the `activity` (the last one has to be wrapped into an `Arrays::asList`).

This will produce a `Stream<List<Address>>`, that further needs to be `flatMapped` and ultimately collected to a `List`, for example.

That would be using a `Stream` approach, though simply creating a new `List` and calling `addAll` twice and `add` once, is still an option.

Comment: you should also concat `activity.getAddresses()`

Comment: There is no Activity.getMan or getWoman

Comment: @nicomp i think it is fair to assume that getters can be used

Comment: 90k, but yet a code-only answer?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose edited.

Comment: @f1sh indeed, though in such a way `concat` would need to be called twice, `Stream::of` is easier.

Comment: There are getters and setters that I have not shown. It is created from xsd schema using jaxb.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method in the `Activity` class that creates a list of all `Address`es. This a very simple approach, but it is easily readable and avoids streams:

```
List<Address> getAllAdresses() {
  List<Address> addr = new LinkedList<>();
  addr.add(address);
  addr.addAll(man.address);
  addr.addAll(woman.address);
  return addr;
}
```

this also allows easy additions of null checks  like `if(man.address==null)`.

Comment: The clean approach I think!

Comment: This class Activity is created from an xsd schema using jaxb. I cannot add any additional function to that class.

Comment: Then create that method in some other class, the logic is the same.